# Simulating vintage blinking cursor in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-animation

I'm developing a WearOS application, and for a specific piece of data I decided — I'm toying with the idea — that the most compact display would be a matrix of dots.

Each dot can be: OFF (almost black, but not totally), ON (vintage green phosphor) and BLINKING (swinging between ON and OFF).

I did it like this:

```kotlin
internal enum class SegmentStatus { OFF, ON, BLINKING }

internal val segment = Modifier.padding(.2f.dp).width(4.dp).height(6.dp).clip(RoundedCornerShape(2.dp))
internal val mapSegmentStateToModifier = mapOf(
    OFF to segment.background(Color.DarkGray),
    ON to segment.background(Color.Green),
    BLINKING to segment.background(Color.White),
)

@Composable
@Preview
fun PreviewDotMapDisplay() {
    val matrix = listOf(
        listOf(ON, ON, ON, ON),
        listOf(ON, ON, ON, OFF),
        listOf(OFF, OFF, OFF, OFF),
        listOf(ON, ON, ON, OFF),
        listOf(ON, ON, ON, BLINKING),
        listOf(ON, OFF, OFF, OFF),
        listOf(OFF, OFF, OFF, OFF),
    )

    Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Black)) {
        matrix.forEach { row ->
            Row {
                row.map { mapSegmentStateToModifier[it] ?: Modifier }
                    .forEach { Spacer(modifier = it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: PreviewDotMapDisplay output]

**How to make that white "dot" blink?** I have no idea

It can be a simple blinking, like fully ON then fully OFF. From there I think I can modify it to add some whistles (ramping up and phosphor overshot, then ramping down and ghosting).

---

Apart from that main question, I'd like also to hear from you about that code above.

Is it too much of a burden on a smart watch to compose that many `Columns` and `Rows` and `Spacer`? The alternative would be to draw those shapes.
— consider that I expect at most 10 lines and 5 columns

Also, that elvis operator in `row.map { mapSegmentStateToModifier[it] ?: Modifier }` annoys me a little, because I know that the else branch is never taken. But kotlin doesn't. Is it possible to create a mapping guaranteed to be exhaustive (with syntax error on constructor if not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with:

```kotlin
    val offColor = Color.DarkGray
    val onColor = Color.Green
    val blinkColor = rememberInfiniteTransition("blinking cursor").animateColor(
        initialValue = offColor,
        targetValue = onColor,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(500),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        ),
        label = "blinking cursor"
    ).value
```

Then I scoped `mapSegmentStateToModifier` to the function (instead of the global scope, because `rememberInfiniteTransition` cannot be called outside `@Composable`):

```kotlin
val mapSegmentStateToModifier = mapOf(
    OFF to segment.background(offColor),
    ON to segment.background(onColor),
    BLINKING to segment.background(blinkColor),
)
```

It did the trick. Now I'll look forward to the other whistles.